# Passing object to function for dynamic function

Tags: javascript

Hi I need to create dynamic function so I am using the following code. In this I want to pass object to function and get it. I tried passing javascript array and it works but javascript object is not working.

### Code:

```
 <button onclick="mainfunc('funct')">button</button>
 <script>
  window.funct = function(){
    alert(arguments);                 //alerts object arguments.
    alert(arguments.a);               //alerts undefined
    alert(JSON.stringify(arguments)); //alerts blank object as {}
  }

  window.mainfunc = function(func){
   var args = {"a":"jhgj","b":"hjgh","c":"hghj"};
   window[func].apply(this, args);
  }
 </script>
```

```js
 window.funct = function(){
  alert(arguments);
  alert(arguments.a);
  alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));
 }

window.mainfunc = function(func){
 var args = {"a":"jhgj","b":"hjgh","c":"hghj"};
 window[func].apply(this, args);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mainfunc('funct')">button</button>
```

### Update:

I am working on Online Flight Booking system. I want to create dynamic function that calls the function created from php loop.

```
 <?php foreach($flightsegment as $data){ $flightnumber = $data->flightnum; ?>
 <li><a href="#fareRules<?= $flightnumber; ?>" data-toggle="tab" onclick="mainfunc('fareRules<?= $flightnumber; ?>', event)">Fare Rules</a></li>
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    window.fareRules<?= $flightnumber; ?> = function () {
        //                                                                            alert(arguments[0].target);
        alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));
        var params = {};
        alert(arguments[1]);
        if (arguments[1] > 1) {   //there is multiple segment
            var segment = arguments[1];
            var logical_gap = segment - 1;
            var dataobj = {};
            for (var o = 2; o < arguments.length; o++) {
                alert(arguments[o + 1]);

            }

        } else {    //there is single segment
            for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                params[i] = arguments[i];
            }
            var target = arguments[0];

            var url = "<?php echo site_url() . '/action/?type=fairbasisrule' ?>";
            var json_upload = "json_name=" + JSON.stringify(params);
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    var len = data.length;
                    //                                                                                console.log(data);
                    var html = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var rules = data[i].rules[0];
                        html += "<b>" + data[i].title + "</b><br><p>" + rules.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') + "</p>";
                    }
                    $(target).parents("td").find('#fareRules<?= $flightnumber; ?>').html(html);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

            xhttp.send(json_upload);
        }
    }
});
</script>

<?php } ?>

 <script>
  window.mainfunc = function (func)
        {
            if ($(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_basiscode').length > 1) {
                var vars = {};

                vars['target'] = arguments[1].target;
                vars['segment_length'] = $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_basiscode').length;
                var z = 0;
                $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_basiscode').each(function () {
                    z++;
                    vars['fair_rule_basiscode' + z] = $(this).text();
                });
                var z = 0;
                $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_departairport').each(function () {
                    z++;
                    vars['fair_rule_departairport' + z] = $(this).text();
                });
                var z = 0;
                $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_arrivalairport').each(function () {
                    z++;
                    vars['fair_rule_arrivalairport' + z] = $(this).text();
                });
                var z = 0;
                $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_airlines').each(function () {
                    z++;
                    vars['fair_rule_airlines' + z] = $(this).text();
                });
                var z = 0;
                $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fairbasisdepartdate').each(function () {
                    z++;
                    vars['fairbasisdepartdate' + z] = $(this).text();
                });
                args = vars;
            } else {

                var fair_rule_basiscode = $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_basiscode').text();
                var fair_rule_departairport = $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_departairport').text();
                var fair_rule_arrivalairport = $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_arrivalairport').text();
                var fair_rule_airlines = $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fair_rule_airlines').text();
                var fairbasisdepartdate = $(arguments[1].target).parents("td").find('.fairbasisdepartdate').text();


                var args = new Array();
                args.push(arguments[1].target);
                args.push(fair_rule_basiscode);
                args.push(fair_rule_departairport);
                args.push(fair_rule_arrivalairport);
                args.push(fair_rule_airlines);
                args.push(fairbasisdepartdate);
            }


            window[func].apply(this, args);
        }

    });
 </script>
```

My goal is sometime there can be multiple flight segment. So I may need to make a multiple ajax request passing the multiple parameter mapping keys with value.

Comment: [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is **always** an array-like object. Why don't you simply specify an argument in your function definition?

Comment: `arguments[0].a`?

Comment: The arguments "object" is not a native object, it's a "[*List* specification type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type)", it does not necessarily behave like an instance of Object. Also see [*ECMA-262 §12.3.6*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-argument-lists).

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic" when you say "dynamic function"? All functions are sort of dynamic by definition.

Comment: @Phil—MDN seems to need some updating. ECMA-262 does not refer to *arguments* as an object any more, it refers to [*Argument Lists*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-argument-lists).

Comment: There's probably a better way whatever you're trying to do can be designed. Give us some more context as to what you're doing and we'll help.

Comment: Given `var args = {...};`, then `window[func].apply(this, args)` will fail since *apply* expects the second parameter to be an Array, not an Object (though you might get away with it if the object has numeric property names and suitable length, i.e. is sufficiently array–like).

Comment: If you just apply(args) and change "arguments" to "this", that seems like what you want.

Comment: @Phil I have case in which I need to pass only array in onc case and object in other case. and also I need to create dynamic function. So I need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is it just doesn't work. The `apply` function expects an array as the second argument and fails if you give it something else. If you really must parse an object and apply it's properties who are in alphabetical order like you have them, you can do that.

```
var args = {"a":"jhgj","b":"hjgh","c":"hghj"};
window[func].apply(this, Object.keys(args).sort().map(function (key) {
  return args[key];
}));
```

If you can support es6 then you can make it a little shorter.

```
var args = {"a":"jhgj","b":"hjgh","c":"hghj"};
window[func].apply(this, Object.keys(args).sort().map(key => args[key]));
```

`Object.keys(args)` returns an array of all the keys on the object as an array: `['a','b','c']`.

`.sort()` with no arguments will return a new array sorted in alphabetical order since [JS objects do not guarantee property order.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

`.map(key => args[key])` iterates the array and creates a new array with the return value from each iteration. In this case we return the value intended to be passed as an argument.

This guarantees that you get a new array with only the values from your object, in alphabetical order of the original object's keys.

Comment: The object I specified in question in alphabeltical order is just a sample. Key in object is not in alphabetical order. Is there any other way to do this. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: That's why I call `sort`. It puts it in alphabetical order if it is not already. If you mean you want to create the array in the order the keys were specified on the original object then that is impossible. Key order is not guaranteed in JavaScript objects. All you can do is use the `.sort()` function. By default it sorts in alphabetical order but you can pass a function to sort however you want: `.sort(function (a, b) { /*compare a to b somehow*/ })`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: With your code I am able to get the object key's value but not the key also. But I need to get key also. I think apply function needs an update.

Comment: No I think your understanding of the apply function needs an update. Forget my code. Whatever you are actually trying to do can probably be done a better way. How about you share the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Ok Sir, Please give me time. I will update the question.